# Images doesn't show up on live Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, image

Why does not my images show up on my the Wordpress site in the Safari web browser? The links are fine, something else is wrong. On my dev environment it works just fine. What can be the fault?

Site: [www.vreta.nu](http://www.vreta.nu)

Comment: I see a lot of images when I open that link (?)

Comment: It doesn't work in Safari for me. But in Crome the images show up.

Comment: Reset the permalinks

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but I tried to change permalinks to default but the images still doesn't appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you got some weird stuff going on with your css. Your setting the content of all img tags to an empty string.[image]

Comment: Aha! I deleted the img selector and it worked great! Thanks for the help! :)